# Convexity of minkowski space when two triangles collide

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, robotics, collision-detection, sumset

I am working on a Python program to show the collision of two triangles by using Minkowski difference. I am subtracting each point from one triangle from every other point on the other triangle. The final shape in the Minkowski space is not convex like I was expecting. The triangles I am using are (1,1)(4,4)(6,1) & (4,2)(7,5)(8,3).

I have attached an image of the collision of the triangles and the Minkowski space.

There are points that are placed in such as way that there is no way to join all the points to make it convex. ( Also one vector (3,1) gets repeated twice on the Minkowski space.The origin has been shown but is not part of the Minkowski difference)

I am not sure what I am missing. Pardon the triangle in the Minkowski space, I am trying to use GJK algo to check for collisions[image]

Comment: What I am realizing now is that only 6 points will create the convex surface, need to think about it a bit more